# Can you give me adjacency list of a graph whose BFS and topological sort are not equivalent?

Tags: data-structures, graph, graph-theory, graph-traversal, topological-sort

Can you give me adjacency list of a graph whose BFS and topological sort are not  equivalent ? I visualze them the same way but googling if they both are same never quite provided a satisfactory answer.

I tried a lot but couldnt think of it.

Comment: Hi. What is it you call a graph? BFS works on anything that is usually called a graph, including directed and undirected graphs. Topological sort only works in a very particular case.

Comment: I suggest that you first determine whether you are thinking of directed graphs or undirected graphs.

Comment: Then, second, after you've decided whether the graphs are directed or undirected, I suggest you draw a small example of a graph that is connected but does not have a cycle, and run a BFS and a topological sort on this example. By "small" I mean about 4 vertices. Let's call G1 this first graph. No need to write the adjacency list, just draw the graph.

Comment: Then draw a second example: a graph that is not connected, let's call it G2. Again, run a BFS and a topological sort on G2. Then draw a small example of a graph that is connected, and has a cycle, let's call it G3. Run a BFS and topological sort on G3. Then collect your findings about differences between BFS and topological sort.

Comment: *"I tried a lot"*: could you edit your question and include your attempts?